What color should "record" / "stop" buttons be?
I have an application with a simple GUI for recording video:

In default state, button says "REC", pressing it starts recording.
While recording, button says "STOP", pressing it stops recording.

This button also serves as the only indicator of whether or not recording is active (since it says "STOP" when it's active and "REC" when it's not).
My question is: What color(s) should this button be to mimic the most common setup in video recording hardware (which I have little experience with)?
My instinct is that "REC" should be red, but then I am not sure what color "STOP" should be, because I also feel like red would indicate "recording in progress".
Note: I cannot change the shape of the button, and I'd prefer not to add an additional recording indicator.

It's not just your instinct. Recorders used to have red REC buttons often. Random example.

Is that 'western' recorders used to have red REC buttons?  Colours mean different things to different cultures.

Sidenote: While "STOP" clearly shows that it is currently running, "REC" could mean that it is currently recording or that it would start recording. Could you perhaps make it instead a more commonly-styled button that always says "REC" but has a clear visual indication that it is currently pressed (e.g. with border shadows "pushing it in")  (or a toggle button that is clearly on)?

While you cannot change the (outer?) shape of the button, can you add interior graphics to simulate a shape change?

Handycam/Camcorder era:

Static physical button for record/stop
Blinking red/solid red indicator light for recordings
Stop is a square icon
Record is a circle icon

Smartphone era:

Dynamic digital button for record/stop
iPhone: after record red record circle click, button icon becomes a stop red square
Samsung camera app: after record red record circle click, button icon becomes a stop dark grey square

Both dark grey and red should be recognizable for stop. REC should def be red. Changing from a circle to square on record would be ideal. Adding a blinking red would also be ideal if you do use any animation. You can safely assume that users will recognize record becomes stop with minimal visual indication, it's a very consistent standard.

If the button has text, I think it is big enough to be able to show with some type of animation that there is an action running, without making a big color change. In this way you not only highlight the subtle difference of the button but also the semantic reinforcement of stopping an action: the recording and the animation.


Be careful to first conduct the appropriate research to ensure you do not induce seizures or migraine headaches with such animations.

I would like an animation in this case, but not THIS animation. As @EndAnti-SemiticHate says, it might not be well perceived. For me, it's too fast, unnecessary angled and why not use something circular, which brings the cassette look and feel back for an old fart like me?

The animation of this answer is a random one, one that I found on the internet customized.

If you go with text, one option would be adding the word "recording" if it fits, ie "Stop recording". Or you could have some indicator nearby with the word "recording"; it can be nice to know what the app does if you for example leave it for a while and get back.

In the physical tape era when record also meant overwrite (and therefore erase) record would be warning-coloured: red or orange.
But for file-based recording there is no need for that to protect your original.
Just use the media controls symbols from Unicode:
⏭ ⏮ ⏯ ⏵ ⏸ ⏹ ⏺ ⏻
etc.
Repeated as an image because some people don't have an appropriate font installed:


How universal is the support for those?  At least on my browser on my work computer, two of them (nr. 4 and nr. 8) are missing glyphs.

For me, the first 3 display as emojis (a white symbol on a rounded box filled with a gradient of bluish gray), the next one just as a black symbol, the next 3 as emojis in the same way again and then logout as a symbol. This inconsistency could not be tolerated IMO. (I am using iPadOS, btw.)

@leo848, even worse on Chrome desktop. The last symbol is missing.

Firefox desktop doesn't render the last symbol either.

The last five are missing on Android Chrome.

I can see all symbols (Firefox 124.0.2, 64-bit, Windows 11).

It isn't Chrome or Firefox or whatnot. It's your fonts. If you expect to see all (or most) possible characters, have at least one font installed that contains a large enough selection.

Chrome v.123 on macOS (Catalina) shows the 4th and 8th buttons as stripey bars

I'm using Firefox 118.5.0esr  so it's probably not a browser version thing.  "chararcter map"  tells me the glyphs are in the font "Noto Sans Symvols2"

@Gábor I also have Firefox installed on the same machine, and the symbols are displayed correctly (all black, as in the second row). So apparently it's not the matter of fonts installed, but fonts used by the browser.

In file-based recording there is absolutely a need for a high-focus visual indication of Record. Usability Heuristic #1 is Visibility of System Status. Record is an important action that has task-based, storage, and legal considerations. If I was auditing an application that's only indication of recording status was a button with a black circle icon changing to a black square icon I would flag it as a heuristic violation.

For this to work, the web browser will have to interpret the content as Unicode; in other words, the content encoding will have to be set correctly.  Also, the required font(s) will need to be downloaded, and the browser will need to have access to them.  Finally, for some browsers, the CSS will need to apply the correct font family.  Ideally, this would all be seamless and offered as a typical standard configuration.  In reality, as the comments above indicate, neither is currently the case.
